# What was the Nature of Resistance in 1938 Czechoslovakia?

Tags: 20th-century, world-war-two, nazi-germany, czechoslovakia

I wonder if someone might help me. I'm writing a novel. My protagonist is a dual national (English born, German parents) bio chemist contracted to work for [Freiburg University](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_Freiburg) 1938. At the time science is deemed useful only if it is practical and he is ordered to travel regularly to Malacky, Slovakia to oversee the development of chemical warfare. His allegiance to the Reich is pragmatic and following one such trip he fails to return to his family in Freiburg. I must decide what happens to him! Or at least I must allude to what might have happened to him given his daughter returns in the 60's to retrace his steps.

I need some background on the Czechoslovakian resistance circa 1938.  Specifically any information related to the structure of the resistance, notable leaders or events, any significant connections between the resistance and/or other groups such as allied intelligence agencies or governments.

Comment: Have you read (or consulted) any of the WW II spy [novels](http://www.alanfurst.net/books) by [Alan Furst](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Furst)? They are very good (and FWIK accurate) on historic background and e.g. *Dark Star* is partly set in Prague (if memory serves correctly.) And BTW, welcome to the site.

Comment: IMHO This question is a bit too localized to be on-topic here. Questions on SE sites really should be capable of being of some use to somebody besides yourself. I'd suggest you tweak it to just ask what, if any underground resistance there might have been in the country after the Sudetenland was annexed, or what the various political factions (above and underground) were in the area during the period (assuming that's what you are asking about)

Comment: This could be rephrased more like "How was Czech resistance structured in Nazi Germany?"

Comment: @Luboš Motl may be able to provide a [good answer](http://history.stackexchange.com/a/4460/1387), as this is partly a question about his home country.

Comment: @Luke: I would characterize your approach as "warm." The way I might structure the question is something like, "Would it have been possible for the Czech resistance in the 1940s to operate something like America's "underground railraod" (for escaped slaves), or were letters successfully smuggled in and out of the Skoda Works in "real life," or  whatever other "mechanic" she wanted to use. That would show "research effort" and a general knowledge of "resistances," meaning that she would only be asking about the Czech variety.

Answer (score 2):

There [wasn't much resistance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czech_resistance_to_Nazi_occupation), at least compared to, e.g., [Belorussia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belarusian_resistance_during_World_War_II).

At first there were some lukewarm boycotts, then the resistance was reduced to intelligence gathering by former army officers directed from London. Heydrich was sent there in the Fall of 1941 and rounded up most of them; when he was assassinated next spring, his successors cracked down and eliminated all that remained.

One has to take into account that Czechs lived under the German rule for 300 years before their independence in 1918. This, of course, does not justify what Germany did, but this can help explain why the transition from independence to Protectorate was relatively peaceful.

Comment: "One has to take into account that Czechs lived under the German rule for 300 years before their independence in 1918. This, of course, does not justify what Germany did, but this can help explain why the transition from independence to Protectorate was relatively peaceful."

That certainly wasn't the case. Czechs and Slovaks were very willing to resist and would have put a great resistance, would the occupation come in 1938. But after the betrayal of UK and France at Munich, the spirit of resistance wore off and by March 1939, most of the unity and will to resist vanished.